# Long standing while trying to create a PDF in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-5, dompdf

I am using `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('myview', $data);                      
//return $pdf->download('pdfview.pdf');                          
return $pdf->stream($nombre_archivo);
```

I am having a problem while trying to use the stream method `$pdf->stream($nombre_archivo);` my app keeps loading forever.

If i use the download method `$pdf->download('pdfview.pdf');` works fine, but I need to use the stream method.

if you could help me, I will be very grateful.

Comment: I am having a problem while trying to use the stream method **$pdf->stream($nombre_archivo);** my app keeps loading forever.

Comment: It's possible that the issue is that the server is expecting more data that is never going to come. One way to test this out is to call `exit(0)` after you call the stream method.

Answer (score 0):

Check the size of records in $data variable, if it has large amount of records the displaying may be slow
or check the barryvdh/laravel-dompdf version and Laravel version,
Sample code

```
public function export_pdf()
    {
        $pdf = PDF::loadHTML('<html><head></head><body>welcome to all</body></html>');
        return $pdf->stream('download.pdf');

    }
```